# What's the solution for the given problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When $242$ is divided by a certain divisor, the remainder obtained is $8$. When $698$ is divided by the same divisor, the remainder obtained is $9$. However, when the sum of the two numbers $242$ and $698$ is divided by the divisor, the remainder obtained is $4$. What is the value of the divisor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The divisor $d$ is a positive integer that divides each of the following three numbers

$242–8=234=2⋅32⋅13,$

$698–9=689=13⋅53,$

and

$(242+698)−4=936=23⋅32⋅13.$

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling with a general divisor formula.